# Expression to complex for Xcode

Tags: xcode, swift

I have a rather complex calculation in Swift and the Xcode (6.2) compiler quits with the following error:

"Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time; consider breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions"

The expression is (the x Values are defined and existent):

matrix11 = (g*(x23*(x12+x32)+x13*(-x22+x32)-(x12+x22)*x33) * sin(a)) / (x13*(x22*x31-x21*x32)+x12*(-x23 * x31+x21 * x33)+x11 * (x23 * x32-x22 * x33))

But regardless of the size of the chunks/slizes of the calculation I do, I always got the same error.

Any hints to solve that problem - thanks in advance

Reto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide the expression into multiple variables, this will improve readability and remove the error.